# How to remove hover effect in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to build an angular app and recently I have one problem.

I have something like this

```
<div ng-class="{selectThis : item.pick}" ng-click="pickItem(item)" class="item">Item name here<div>
```

JS controller:

```
$scope.pickItem = function(item) {
    item.pick = true;
}
```

Css:

```
.item {
    color: red;
    …more css
}

.item:hover {
    color:blue;
    ...more css
}

.selectThis {
    color:blue;
}
```

It works well on desktop but the hover effect will remain on touch device when user touches the div. I know I can add the media query to solve this but I  think that's a outdated approach. Is there anyways I can solve it with Angular way? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you add more code for this? There is no insight into what `item.pick` is doing. Could one assume that `item.pick` is being handled by the "touch" event? If that's the case, then the issue is because both `.selectThis` and `.item:hover` style `color` are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it with Angular by adding a class when a touch events are fired:

```
app.directive('touchClass', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      touchClass: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {   
      element.on('touchstart', function() {
        element.$addClass(scope.touchClass);
      });

      element.on('touchend', function() {
        element.$removeClass(scope.touchClass);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Then you can add this directive to any element you want. It will add the `touch` class whilst there is a touch in progress and it will remove it when the touch is over.

```
<div ng-class="{selectThis : item.pick}"
     ng-click="pickItem(item)"
     touch-class="touch"
     class="item">
  Item name here
<div>
```

You can treat this class almost like the hover pseudo selector:

```
.item {
  color: red;
  …more css
}

.item.touch {
  color:blue;
  ...more css
}

.selectThis {
  color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something on the touch events:

```
<div ng-class=="{ 'touch': touchStart}"
  on-touch
 class="item">Item name here<div>
```

And make a directive which handles the touch event

```
    .directive('onTouch',function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
                $elem.on('touchstart',function(e) {
                    $scope.touchStart= true;
                    $scope.$apply();
                });
                $elem.on('touchend',function(e) {
                    $scope.touchStart= false;
                    $scope.$apply();
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

PD: i didn't try this code, is just a draft. I hope it helps